# Error with compiling my code

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm using Android Studio.I get Errors at some lines of code
[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PSnd.jpg)
So how can I fix it ?

My xml files I used in the project :

roundrec:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke android:width="10dip"  android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<corners android:radius="9dip"/>
<padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
```

Comment: Your source code link is a 404, but your error link indicates you are missing a drawable resource called `roundrec`

Comment: First add roundrec image in your drawable folder.

Comment: No,Because the content of this file is shown on the preview

Comment: The file is already in drawable folder

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Then please update your question with the error stated by the red circle next to that line.

Comment: There's no Description about the Error

Comment: that roundrect is .xml file in your drawable right?

Comment: are you able to run app? or not?

Comment: run your app i think your app is run perfectly

Comment: yes, it's a xml file

Comment: show my answer. use like that.

Comment: yes, I want to run the app

Comment: Use always `android:background` with drawable file which is shown in my answer below.

Comment: are you getting any error while you trying to run app? i guess you must be able to run app without any issue

Comment: yes, when I run the emulator or my phone the app doesn't work properly

Comment: Now at java class ,The R class has Error "Cannot Resolve symbol 'R' "

Comment: I think that's why the application couldn't run properly

Comment: This is your whole drawable xml file? see my updated answer.

Comment: my project is based on this drawable xml file just like: edit text,buttons,even image views.
the imageview has two drawable files a picture and this xml file

Comment: @ChiragSavsani: That's not the problem now ,the problem is the R Class has an error "cannot resolve symbol 'R' "

Comment: @MahmoudMado For resolve R Class error, I always use clean project. That works for me always. But If any error is present then Project can not build. and if project not build, R file is not generated.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
android:background="@drawable/roundrect"
```

// Sample of drawable file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270" 
        android:startColor="#FBFBFC"
        android:endColor="#E7E9EC">
    </gradient>

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="2dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="2dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="2dip"
        android:topRightRadius="2dip" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#BCC1C8" />

</shape>
```

Comment: move your mouse cursor on error or on roundract, You can't see any error message?

Comment: No,I can't see Errors, Just the red one

Comment: Ok just try my code and clean project. Look what's happen?

Comment: I tried in my code. It gives me error while I user drawable.xml file in src . So you have to use background with drawable.xml file.

Comment: I tried it now The Errors is as following:

Note:this project has java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views. Fix the compilation problems first.

1-onMessure error

At the java file I get an Error at R class

Answer (score 0):

Put roundrect image in drawable folder.

Comment: roundrect isn't an image , It's a xml file

Comment: That xml file should draw a rounded rectangle and it does.

Comment: @MahmoudMado `roundrect isn't an image , It's a xml file` And who told you that the `drawable` folder is for images only? Every **drawable** has to go there. Otherwise, the folde would be called `image`

Answer (score -1):

Put image in durable folder. Give image roundrect
`android:background**="@drawable/roundrect"**`